# JSON stringify issue with NodeJS and EJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ejs, stringify

I am doing this

```
var o = <%- JSON.stringify(object) %>;
```

in a code with following output

```
var o = {"_id":"57bafa202acb57b8ab000013","status":"incomplete","title":"<script>alert(1);</script>","updated_at":"2016-08-22T18:42:00+05:30","id":"57bafa202acb57b8ab000013"};
```

and the following error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

There is a title attribute with a "<script>alert(1);</script>" in the object.
How do I deal with this?

Comment: When does the error occur? Clearly the `JSON.stringify` is not failing if you have that output.

Comment: Its failing at this line itself. JSON.stringify works fine.   var o = <%- JSON.stringify(object) %>;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the `<`'s, for instance by using a Unicode escape:

```
var o = <%- JSON.stringify(object).replace(/</g, '\\u003c') %>;
```

Comment: That worked. Would you suggest any other characters apart from `<` and `>` that should be escaped with unocode? Also how does this work but the above code doesn't. `var a = {"title":"<script>alert(1);</script>"};
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a))`

Comment: The `&` would be a good candidate as well. The main issue is that you're mixing HTML with JS, and both have their own set of special characters. For HTML, `</`, even in JS code, starts the end of an element.